# How to parse the json array of the format below

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, go

```
    {
    "machines": [{
        "name": "relay_1",
        "totalmem": "3G",
        "machinemem": "6G"
    }, {
        "name": "relay_2",
        "totalmem": "30G",
        "machinemem": "4G"
    }]
}
```

tried doing the parsing using the below code

```
Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
                fmt.Println("relay called")
                conf, _ = rootCmd.Flags().GetString("conf")
                if conf != "" {
                        fmt.Println("From Create Command : ", conf)
                }
                data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("file.txt") // data has type []byte
                if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                }
                var result []map[string]interface{}
                json.Unmarshal(data, &result)
                relays := result["relays"].(map[string]interface{})
                for key, relay := range relays {
                        fmt.Println("name :", relay["name"],
                                "totalmem:", relay["totalmem"],
                                "relaymem:", relay["relaymem"])

                }
        },
```

But I am getting the error as below which indicates that the type is invalid

cmd/create_relay.go:54:29: invalid type assertion: result["relays"].(map[string]) (non-interface type map[string]interface {} on left)

Can someone let me know how to parse the json below by using the interfaces as below

Comment: Unmarshal into a proper struct.

Comment: Your example JSON is incomplete, please come up with a [mcve] (it's enough to hard-code the JSON in the example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with the below code.

```
type Relays struct {
    Relays []Relay `json:"relays"`
}

type Relay struct {
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Totalmem   string `json:"totalmem"`
    Relaymem   string    `json:"relaymem"`
}

// relayCmd represents the relay command
var createrelayCmd = &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "relay",
        Short: "A brief description of your command",
        Long: `A longer description that spans multiple lines and likely contains examples
and usage of using your command. For example:

Cobra is a CLI library for Go that empowers applications.
This application is a tool to generate the needed files
to quickly create a Cobra application.`,
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
                fmt.Println("relay called")
                conf, _ = rootCmd.Flags().GetString("conf")
                if conf != "" {
                        fmt.Println("From Create Command : ", conf)
                        jsonFile, err := os.Open(conf)
                        // if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
                        if err != nil {
                                fmt.Println(err)
                        }
                        fmt.Println("Successfully Opened users.json")
                        // defer the closing of our jsonFile so that we can parse it later on
                        defer jsonFile.Close()
                        data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile) // data has type []byte
                        if err != nil {
                                log.Fatal(err)
                        }
                        var relays Relays
                        json.Unmarshal(data,&relays)
                        for i := 0; i < len(relays.Relays); i++ {
                                fmt.Println("User Name: " + relays.Relays[i].Name)
                                fmt.Println("User Totalmem: " + relays.Relays[i].Totalmem)
                                fmt.Println("User Relaymem: " + relays.Relays[i].Relaymem)
                        }
                }
        },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` in your code is an array of map and you are using `result["relays"]` which is invalid.

Your code should be something like this:

```
Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            fmt.Println("relay called")
            conf, _ = rootCmd.Flags().GetString("conf")
            if conf != "" {
                    fmt.Println("From Create Command : ", conf)
            }
            data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("file.txt") // data has type []byte
            if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
            }
            var result map[string]interface{}
            json.Unmarshal(data, &result)
            relays := result["relays"].([]interface{})
            for _, relay := range relays {
                    relayM := relay.(map[string]interface{})
                    fmt.Println("name :", relayM["name"].(string),
                            "totalmem:", relayM["totalmem"].(string),
                            "relaymem:", relayM["relaymem"].(string))

            }
    },
```